# Perform actions offline for users authenticated with IdentityServer3

Tags: openid-connect, identityserver3

In my project I am using IdentityServer3 with several external identity providers (via ADFS) and everything is working great. However, I'd like to perform some actions on behalf of the user in the background via a scheduled task - when they are offline.

Before I switched over to OpenId Connect I only had local users and just created a Principal for the user and "impersonated" them. Now that I have external users I want to replace this functionality and I believe that using a Refresh token is the correct way to do this.

I plan to store the Refresh token for each user securely in our database each time the user visits the site. The refresh token will then be used to get a valid access token when the scheduled task runs and use this to call into the backend webapi. This will achieve the impersonation I require and also deal with the new problem with external users that I dont know when they have been disabled/deleted from the external user store, and I dont want to leave scheduled tasks still running in the system as their linked account is still valid, e.g. if they access is removed, the stored refresh token will eventually expire and the scheduled tasks will stop running.

Is this the best/correct way to deal with offline actions? I'm worried that I've made a requirement that the user must login periodically to ensure we have a valid refresh token stored. Or is there a better way of enabling offline access indefinitely yet still secure.

Answer (score 0):

Refresh tokens are a technique to get long lived access to APIs without user interaction. That seems to satisfy your requirement.

Comment: If I wanted to avoid Refresh tokens, and all I need is an access token to pass into a webapi backend, could I use a service account to login with resource owner password flow, and then ActAs the other user (using a custom grant?). I really only need a JWT access token built for my user that I'm running a task for - I dont need any claims from their IdP, just those i add from our own database. This sounds like what I need, but I'm not familiar with custom grants in IdSvr3 yet but the samples look like I could use this as a type of impersonation?